# ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter: how to notify the fragment instance that it's being switched to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ViewPager`, `FragmentPagerAdapter` and a couple fragments. I need to notify the fragment when the user switches to a different one (so that the first one can finalize its work). I'm looking into `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` but can't see any way to get the current fragment instance when the change occurs. Even `ViewPager.getCurrentItem()` returns the new position when `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected` is called.

Is it guaranteed that `Fragment.onPause()` will be called for the previous fragment every time when a new one is selected? That would certainly simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation is seems onPause gets call when ever  user leave the fragment (though it does not always mean the fragment is being destroyed).

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Apparently not, I've put a break point there and it's not being hit when I move back and forth between two fragments.

Comment: its looks fine let me check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html sample then i will share that code with you.

Comment: ok i implemented and tested android code and it calls onPause method here is https://github.com/yasirali1234/testfragment.git

Comment: I don't understand why, but in my app `onPause` isn't getting called for either of the two fragments. But it is when I leave the app. Google Nexus 7 2013, the official Android 6 firmware.

Comment: Is it because adapter has some sort of lazy loading mean it just keeps reference of recently removed fragment?

Comment: Not that I know of. The adapter is literally exactly what I've show in the gist linked above. I will check whether `getItem` is called every time a transition occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference of your fragment at class level, as `mCustomFragment`.
Then inside your fragment setup a public method which will finalize the work, you simply call this method when you need it in the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: No, I don't see how to make it work. Let's say I store the reference to current fragment in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem`, but by the time `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected` is called it's already too late. I know which fragment I'm switching **to**, but not which **from**.

Comment: And I don't even think `getItem` is necessarily called each time a transition occurs. It could be cached internally.

Comment: Ok I see your point. No need to get it from getItem(). What about keeping track of your current viewpager page? You could use anything, an index, a string. Then, onPageSelected, you get your reference based on the object you're storing your last page reference, and call a method eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe attach some sort of gesture listener to determine which way the swipe occurs. Then on OnPageChangeListener based on the last gesture used before the call, determine whether to put +1 or -1 on the current viewpager index.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of getting the fragment _instance_.

Comment: Ok then why not make a custom adapter class, and create a method that returns a fragment based on the index pass into it? Guess I just don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that actually works. It involves broadcasts for notifying the fragments.

First, I extended the `Fragment` class:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class ExtendedFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String FragmentIdTag = "Fragment ID";
    public static final String FragmentSwitchedEventId = "FragmentSwitchedEvent";

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    protected ExtendedFragment(FragmentType fragmentId) {
        m_fragmentType = fragmentId;
    }

    public void onSwitchedAway() {
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver() {
        return m_receiver;
    }

    class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            FragmentType newFragmentType = (FragmentType) intent.getSerializableExtra(FragmentIdTag);
            if (newFragmentType != m_fragmentType)
                onSwitchedAway();
        }
    }

    protected final FragmentType m_fragmentType;
    Receiver m_receiver = new Receiver();
}
```

`FragmentType` is `enum` that's different for every fragment. All the fragments extend `ExtendedFragment` (a terrible name, I know. Feel free to suggest a better one) and pass appropriate unique `FragmentType` value to its constructor.

Then I use the `Viewpager.OnPageChangeListener` to detect the fragment switch:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                FragmentType newType = fragmentTypeForPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(ExtendedFragment.FragmentSwitchedEventId);
                i.putExtra(ExtendedFragment.FragmentIdTag, newType);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
```

And finally, when instantiating the fragments don't forget to register them as broadcast receivers:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                FragmentType newType = fragmentTypeForPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(ExtendedFragment.FragmentSwitchedEventId);
                i.putExtra(ExtendedFragment.FragmentIdTag, newType);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        });
```

Done. Now the fragments can override `public void onSwitchedAway()`.